# Angular 6 query param in the middle of a routerlink

Tags: angular, typescript

How do you put a parameter into a `routerlink`.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers">
   <a [routerLink]="['/supplier/{{supplier.businessId}}/products']">
        View Products
   </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Do it like this : --   <a routerLink="/product/productDetails/{{item.product.id}}" title="Edit">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>

Comment: Perfect! What's the difference between routerlink and [routerlink] ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access query params in routerlink like below.

```
 <a routerLink="/product/productDetails/{{item.product.id}}" title="Edit"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>
```

**What is difference between routerLink and [routerLink] ?**

As per your question in routerLink you can directly use queryparams as shown in above code but in [routerLink] you can set queryparams like this.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}" fragment="education">
  link to user component
</a>
```

For more information visit this link : https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 5):

```
routerlink=""
```

This will assign what is put on the right side of the `=`. If there is an expression with `{{}}`, it will be evaluated and assigned.

Example - `routerlink="something"` - Here something will be assigned to the `routerlink` as ***string***

```
 [routerlink]=""
```

`[]` forces the right side of the `=` to be evaluated.

Example - `[routerlink]="something"` - Here something will be evaluated as ***property*** and engine will try to find a property with name `something` on the component, evaluate it and then assign the value to the `routerLink`.

Comment: This one's actually more simple to understand then my answer. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Angular you're using, but you can also do the following:

```
<p *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers">
   <a [routerLink]="['/supplier', supplier.businessId, 'products']">
        View Products
   </a>
</p>
```

This will do away with the need for the braces `{{ }}`.